# Count popular Rows in table, Match Ids to names in OTHER table

Tags: php, count

I'm trying to call up the 10 most popular post_ids entered in a table called postmeta.

There is also a separate table called posts, and it contains post titles, post content and ids.

what I want to do is first figure out which post_ids have the most postmeta entries, and then also query the 'posts' table and match the post_ids to post names. I want to output the post name related to the 10 most popular ids, followed by a count of the entries. Ex:

apples(152)
bears(80)
pie(31)
oranges(12)

I'm a bit new to PHP and can't figure out how to query both of these tables to get what I want.
So far I have this to get the count:

```
global $wpdb;
$popularity = "
select post_id, count(post_id) as cnt
from $wpdb->postmeta
group by post_id
order by cnt desc
limit 10";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$popularity = "SELECT pm.post_id, COUNT(pm.post_id) AS cnt, p.title
                FROM $wpdb->postmeta pm JOIN $wpdb->posts p
                ON pm.post_id = p.id GROUP BY pm.post_id ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 10";
```

You didn't give enough information on the separate table, so I'm assuming the column names in that table are `title` and `id`.

Comment: That's fine. I can't seem to get an output using foreach ($wpdb->get_results($popularity) as $row) {
            $post_title = $row->post.post_title;
        $id = $row->ID;
        echo $post_title.$id;

Comment: They won't be selected with the table name, they'll just be the name of the column. So if selected `post.post_title` it would return `post_title`